# Column is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to insert records on my trying to implement an SCD2 on Redshift
but get an error.

The target table's DDL is

```
CREATE TABLE ditemp.ts_scd2_test (
    id INT
    ,md5 CHAR(32)
    ,record_id BIGINT IDENTITY
    ,from_timestamp TIMESTAMP
    ,to_timestamp TIMESTAMP
    ,file_id BIGINT
    ,party_id BIGINT
    )
```

This is the insert statement:

```
INSERT
INTO ditemp.TS_SCD2_TEST(id, md5, from_timestamp, to_timestamp)

SELECT TS_SCD2_TEST_STAGING.id
    ,TS_SCD2_TEST_STAGING.md5
    ,from_timestamp
    ,to_timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT '20150901 16:34:02' AS from_timestamp
        ,CASE 
            WHEN last_record IS NULL
                THEN '20150901 16:34:02'
            ELSE '39991231 11:11:11.000'
            END AS to_timestamp
        ,CASE 
            WHEN rownum != 1
                AND atom.id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
            WHEN atom.id IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS transfer
        ,stage.*
    FROM (
        SELECT id
        FROM ditemp.TS_SCD2_TEST_STAGING
        WHERE file_id = 2
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING count(*) > 1
        ) AS scd2_count_ge_1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY id ORDER BY record_id
                ) AS rownum
            ,stage.*
        FROM ditemp.TS_SCD2_TEST_STAGING AS stage
        WHERE file_id IN (2)
        ) AS stage
        ON (scd2_count_ge_1.id = stage.id)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT max(rownum) AS last_record
            ,id
        FROM (
            SELECT row_number() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY record_id
                    ) AS rownum
                ,stage.*
            FROM ditemp.TS_SCD2_TEST_STAGING AS stage
            )
        GROUP BY id
        ) AS last_record
        ON (
                stage.id = last_record.id
                AND stage.rownum = last_record.last_record
                )
    LEFT JOIN ditemp.TS_SCD2_TEST AS atom
        ON (
                stage.id = atom.id
                AND stage.md5 = atom.md5
                AND atom.to_timestamp > '20150901 16:34:02'
                )
    ) AS TS_SCD2_TEST_STAGING
WHERE transfer = 1
```

and to short things up, I am trying to insert `20150901 16:34:02` to `from_timestamp` and `39991231 11:11:11.000` to `to_timestamp`.

and get

`ERROR: 42804: column "from_timestamp" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying`

Can anyone please suggest how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Postgres isn't recognizing `20150901 16:34:02` (your input) as a valid time/date format, so it assumes it's a string.

Use a standard date format instead, preferably ISO-8601. `2015-09-01T16:34:02`

[SQLFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/82262/5)

Answer (score 16):

Just in case someone ends up here trying to insert into a postgresql a `timestamp` or a `timestampz` from a variable in groovy or Java from a prepared statement and getting the same error (as I did), I managed to do it by setting the property `stringtype` to `"unspecified"`. According to the [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters):

> Specify the type to use when binding PreparedStatement parameters set
>   via setString(). If stringtype is set to VARCHAR (the default), such
>   parameters will be sent to the server as varchar parameters. If
>   stringtype is set to unspecified, parameters will be sent to the
>   server as untyped values, and the server will attempt to infer an
>   appropriate type. This is useful if you have an existing application
>   that uses setString() to set parameters that are actually some other
>   type, such as integers, and you are unable to change the application
>   to use an appropriate method such as setInt().

```
Properties props = [user : "user", password: "password", 
driver:"org.postgresql.Driver", stringtype:"unspecified"]
def sql = Sql.newInstance("url", props)
```

With this property set, you can insert a timestamp as a string variable without the error raised in the question title. For instance:

```
String myTimestamp= Instant.now().toString()
sql.execute("""INSERT INTO MyTable (MyTimestamp) VALUES (?)""",
[myTimestamp.toString()]
```

This way, the type of the timestamp (from a String) is inferred correctly by postgresql. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Inside apache-tomcat-9.0.7/conf/server.xml

Add "`?stringtype=unspecified`" to the end of url address. 
For example:

```
<GlobalNamingResources> 
<Resource name="jdbc/??" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
       ...
       url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/Local_DB?stringtype=unspecified"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```